# Weird output of following simple Python list program

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**I am getting bit confused after seeing the output of following Python program:**

```
a = [0,1,2,3]

for a[-1] in a:

    print(a[-1])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0

1

2

2
```

Here, I have taken a list `[0,1,2,3]` which gives the `output: 0 1 2 2` but I have expected the output would be `3 3 3 3` since a[-1] accesses the number 3 in the list. Please someone help me to clear my doubt.

Comment: It would be easier to see what's going on if you printed the entire list on each iteration of the loop.  `3` is not a possible part of the result, because you overwrote that value on the first iteration.

Comment: Weird downvotes here. Someone should say that `for a[-1] in a` should *never* be used, as shouldn't `for a in a`. It is a can of worms to assign the item to the same variable as the list. Sure, you could do it, but you open yourself to nasty bugs.

Answer (score 0):

For each entry, you are assigning the value to `a[-1]` which is the last entry and printing it. When you get to the last entry, it has the value of the second last entry hence 2 appears twice.

So you first set the value of `a[3]` to `0` and output that, then set the value of `a[3]` to 1 and output that etc.

You can verify this by printing the list after your loop's completion:

```py
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: This can be verified by printing the list after the loop's completion.

Answer (score -1):

This is how your code is working: For every item in the list, define each item a[-1] and then print the item, called a[-1]. At the last entry it has the value of the second last entry so 2 appears two times. If you want to print the value of the list a[-1] 3 times, try this:

```py
for i in range(0, 4):
   print(a[-1])
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot bind to `a[-1]` it is not a legal variable name. That said I am surprised it is not exploding due to this.

A legal variation of this would be

```
for i in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

Though usually this is not necessary - i remains unused.

You could also do

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    print(a[-1])
```

It is unclear what you want to achieve though. If you want to print the last elements x number of times, where x is the number of elements, there are other solutions.

This would probably be my goto:

```
[a[-1]] * len(a)
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that the code you are trying to write looks more like this:

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
for number in a:
     print(a[-1])
```

when you do a for loop (for X in Y) Y should be a variable that exists and X should not be the name of an existing variable or a reference to a part of a variable or anything of the sort. X should simply be a new name you are making up to refer to each of the things inside Y. You using a[-1] for x caused my head to explode; just stick to using a new name for X.